# How to set height of google maps infoWindow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a marker with an info window here http://waterski.allthingswebdesign.com/index.php/site/directions and if you click the marker, the info window has a scroll bar. I don't want that scroll bar to be there. How can I make it so the height is calculated correctly without adding a scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this,

```
div.infowindow {
    max-height:250px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

this may be work good.
Thanks.